# Laravel - Convert list object to key value

Tags: laravel, list, key-value

I have a list object like:

```
"my_list": 
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": A
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": B
  },
]
```

I want to convert to key - value like:

```
my_list = {
 1: 'A',
 2: 'B'
}
```

How can I do that? Does anyone have solution? 
Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Cast it to Laravel collection and use `mapWithKeys()`

```
$keyed = collect($my_list)->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item['id'] => $item['name']];
});
```

If you need to convert it to object then:

```
$keyed = (object)$keyed->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-pluck) combines with [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.combine):

```php
(object)array_combine(Arr::pluck($my_list, 'id'), Arr::pluck($my_list, 'name'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this.